# Do children of gods have powers in The Almighty Johnsons?

Tags: the-almighty-johnsons

In *The Almighty Johnsons*, we learn that Olaf/Baldr has had numerous children with mortal women.  Since Olaf is a god, by a normal definition these children would be demi-gods, and have some sort of supernatural abilities of their own.

Has this been addressed in the show?  Are the children normal mortals (perhaps because of the weaker powers of their parents), or do they have some sort of god-powers too?

Comment: +1 for asking about this wonderful show.

Comment: @SchroedingersCat two questions, so that the tag doesn't get wiped away :)  I'm embarrassed that it's taken me this long (considering I am in NZ) to watch it - I had no idea it was so good.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the godness is something that they need two divine parent for, and even then they need to accept their godness when they come to a certain age ( as per the first episode ).

Having said that, the gods are reasonably weak, compared with what they should be. I suspect that diluting this with more humanity, any powers would be miniscule. They may be demi-gods, but even full gods are pretty pathetic.

It might be that when Odin finds Frig - if ever - things might change.

Comment: This is correct and is even referenced in the show - look at Thor's daughter.